# How M.2 SSD could aftect other PCIe devices (4x 1080Ti)?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express

I have dataset which consist of jpg files with size 100-300 KB with overall size of ~100 GB. Which I want to read fast and in random order. I have a server with ASUS x99-E WS motherboard with x4 1080Ti on it. I want to install SSD on it (960 EVO Samsung) with M.2 because of its speed. But I want to know how this SSD would affect my GPUs? Will it dramatically reduce speed of CPU<->GPU connection or even disable some of 1080?

Comment: There is but one resource that contains information about potential changes in lane assignment: Your motherboard’s manual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently that motherboard has a PLX chip providing 48 additional PCI-E lanes.  So even with those cards all running at 16x, you should have 24 or 12 lanes free (depending on your CPU).

Comment: I have 6850K it have 40 lanes

Comment: Yes, and a PLX8747 chip which adds 48 lanes, so 88 lanes total.  In other words, you have plenty of headroom for an M.2 SSD

Comment: Sounds awesome)))

Comment: You're missing the fact that the PLX chip needs to be connected to the CPU. Those 48 lanes are 16 upstream+32 downstream, and the 16 upstream have to be *deducted* from the 40 of the CPU.

Comment: Fair enough, he still has enough for a 4x M.2 regardless.

Comment: Doing more reading, this is a whole lot more of a grey area than I thought, since there is an NDA on the technical details of the PLX chips.  The most reliable information seems to be that they don't add lanes at all, they are basically switches.  Long story short, all of your devices should work fine, the motherboard will intelligently distribute the load via the PLX switches.  I suppose this could introduce some latency, but this would already be experienced when using 4 x 1080ti's since the switches will already be in use, adding a 4x M.2 is unlikely to cause any perceivable slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Machine Learning setup. The bandwidth of a 1080Ti is very high, far more than you need for Machine Learning. It's dimensioned to play games at 4K, 60 FPS, taking 16 lanes.

So yes, you'll likely encounter a theoretical slowdown as there aren't enough PCI-e lanes. You'd need an AMD Threadripper to drive that many cards at those resolutions and framerates. On the X99 platform, with 28 lanes total, you can't even give 8 lanes to each card.

But for machine learning, most of the time is spent doing math. The communication speed between CPU and GPU is far less of a limit. After all, you only get the input data in from a single SSD, so that is likely going to be the limit. And even if the SSD itself wouldn't be a limit, the M2 slot is limited to just 4 lanes, so having 4 lanes towards each 1080Ti isn't an issue either.

[edit]
Checking the particular setup of the Asus X99-WS it appears to use two PLX chips to multiplex 2x16 lanes into 4x16 lanes towards the 4 GPU's. That means each can reach a peek speed of x16, but not simultaneously. Still doesn't matter, it remains M2-bottlenecked.

Comment: Yes I do ML on it. So you say that I have 40 lanes from CPU (6850K) + 28 additional lanes from motherboard, 68 in total?

Comment: @MaratZakirov: See edit